# Show pandas framework as html from csv file

Tags: html, django, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to show csv files on html content but I havent done properly up to now. Want to show html content without using models because the length or headers is not fixed this is dependable on tasks. This doesnt show proper format.
Code;

```
df = pd.read_csv(f_path)
objects = df.to_html(header=None)return
HttpResponse(objects)
```

csv content

[image]

html output

[image]

Comment: i) That's not really a CSV file then, as it is separated with `;` - try passing `sep=";"` to `pd.read_csv`. ii) Are you sure that's the whole file content? Pandas wouldn't make up those extra 4 rows, i believe.

Comment: sep=";" works for seperating elements but what do you mean by saying this is not real csv file. I opened an excel csv file to try my code.  I can upload all content of my csv fie you can check it. I missplaced a border that can make an error about content.

Comment: CSV stands for comma-separated values whereas yours is ;-separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling out the separator in your data, which looks to be `;`. Also set your index to be the first column and establish your column names.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', index_col=0)
df.columns =['Epoch', 'Data']
```